# Custom ESP32-C3 board does not connect to PC

Tags: pcb, esp32

When I connect the system to a PC I get the message that the device is recognized. After 10 seconds the system logs off (classic Windows disconnect sound,) then the sound repeats itself without playing the connect sound.

The 5V and 3.3V rails are stable. I have checked with an oscilloscope and there are no voltage drops.

To debug the hardware I only soldered USB1, H1 U3 and all resistors and capacitors on the board. The error remains.

I have built several of the boards and the error is the same on all of them.

I suspect that I have overlooked something important with my design. I have followed the basic circuit for the C3 family of Espressif (should it at least.)

I have attached the schematic, BOM and PCB layout as pictures.

[image: Schematic]

[image: BOM]

[image: PCB]

**EDIT 1**

I found a [project using the same technology and same routing style that seems to work.](https://hackaday.io/project/187504-esp32-3-channel-power-logger) It uses another package. Maybe it's just a coincidence that it works for this project.

[image: PCB Working form other project with similar stucture]

According to the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_datasheet_en.pdf), the USB2.0 full speed standard is implemented.

[Following this, they must not only be routed as an impedance-controlled differential pair, but a distance of 2.4inches (10% limit) or 6 inches (25% limit) should not be exceeded](https://resources.altium.com/p/routing-requirements-usb-20-2-layer-pcb). I will design a new PCB with the appropriate specifications and check if it has succeeded.

**EDIT 2**
The whole thing does not seem as sensitive as addressed. In this [article someone has managed to build the circuit with a plug-in board](https://semjonov.de/posts/2021-09/tinkering-with-an-esp32-c3-module/). Maybe there is something wrong with the microcontroller I ordered.

Comment: You can't route the USB D+ & D- traces like that & expect it to work properly. They need to be routed together as an impedance-controlled differential pair.

Comment: The other PCB layout you've added shows the USB data pair routed together for the entire length. Yours however has them what looks like almost an inch apart for almost 1/3 of the length. That's not the "same routing style" at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to fix. I probably should have routed D+/D- better, and I will in my next design, but it is not the cause of the behavior. I could have installed new firmware on the chip all along. The default firmware just seems to reset the chip every three seconds.  You can just overwrite it with your program. I had thought that the chip / PCB was faulty because of the shutdown, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the schematic and layout for the ESP32-C3-DevKitC-02 found [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/hw-reference/esp32c3/user-guide-devkitc-02.html) you'll see that they haven't actually directly connected the USB bus to the ESP32, but it's going through a good old CP2102. Though the footprints R2 and R3 are placed so the connection could be made.

Exactly why they've done this I don't know, as there are clearly the pins to do a direct connection, but I'd be inclined to think that there is a reason. Looking at the ESP32 datasheet itself, figure 7 shows a direct connection of the USB port, but the capacitor values are suspiciously marked TBD. My guess, this part isn't totally figured out yet, so they've used a bridge for now.

Also, a question, do you have the appropriate drivers downloaded?

Comment: In the ESP32-C3DevKit, they use the RX / TX Interface and not the USB Interface, so you can connect CDC Devices to the controller. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-guides/usb-serial-jtag-console.html.